# Selecting the number of cycles for wavelet transform

Tags: frequency, wavelet

I'm trying some wavelet analysis of EEG signals, using the phase lock measures
from [[1]](http://brainimaging.waisman.wisc.edu/~lutz/LeVanQuyen_et_all_JNM_2001.pdf), specifically the S-PLV measure.

In order to calculate that we perform a wavelet transform on the signals and
one of the parameters we have to set is the number of cycles for the wavelet.

The authors suggest that the number of cycles is

$nco = 6 f σ$

where $f$ is the frequency at which we are creating the wavelet transform at
and $σ$ is proportional to the inverse of $f$.

The authors mention that in most of their studies they used $nco$ between 3 and 8,
but I was wondering:

**Is there any benefit in varying the number of cycles for different frequencies?**

In my case I am calculating the Wavelet transform for a number of bands ranging
from 1Hz to 100Hz, so setting the number to a constant seems like a bad idea
given the wide spectrum of frequencies.

[1] : [Comparison of Hilbert transform and wavelet methods for the analysis of neuronal synchrony](http://brainimaging.waisman.wisc.edu/~lutz/LeVanQuyen_et_all_JNM_2001.pdf)